# TypeError for datetime object, when shifting DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I am using pandas shift function to calculate returns for a dataset of prices. My index are the corresponding dates. For some reason, I get a TypeError, when shifting the dataset (second row of the code mentioned below):

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

My dataset looks like this:
[image]

The Index is converted to a datetime object, using `pd.to_datetime(price_data_local.index)`.

The code for the part, when the error arises looks like this:

```
price_data_local.replace("NULL",np.nan)
weekl_rtr_local = price_data_local/price_data_local.shift(1) - 1
weekl_rtr_local.drop(datetime.date(2010,1,1),inplace = True)
```

Ideally, this would calculate the relative difference and drop the first row.

Why do I get an error?

Thank you for your help!

Kind regards,
semicolon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here was, that excel converted some parts of my .csv from numbers to strings, that then got converted into datetime objects by pandas. I had to manually fix this in my .csv file.